# rbenv install crashing Mac Yosemite

Tags: ruby, rbenv, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to install ruby 2.2.2 using rbenv. All that happens is that my mac crashes and shuts down.

Here's all that I ran.

```
rbenv install 2.2.0
```

I've tried with the previous stable version too.

```
rbenv install 2.1.6
```

The same result the systems crashes and shuts down. 
When I do

```
rbenv versions
* system (set by /Users/home/.rbenv/version)
  2.1.6
  2.2.2
```

However when I do

```
rbenv rehash
rbenv global 2.2.2
```

It still continues with the old version.

```
| => ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
```

Any idea what could be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing after turn off Kaspersky, and then install went OK.
Try turn off antivirus type software and then undo and redo installation.

rbenv uninstall x.x.x
rbenv versions (check if uninstalled)
rbenv install x.x.x